# How does this read in files?

Tags: c, pointers, file-io

I've been trying to figure out how this code reads in a file. I've been trying to get this to work however it just crashes every time. Can someone explain how this is supposed to read in files.?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(argc,argv)
   int argc;
   char **argv;
{
    FILE    *fo1, *fo2,*fp1, *fopen();
    char    *foobar;

    argc--; argv++;      
    foobar = *argv;
    fp1=fopen(foobar,"rb");

    argc--; argv++;     
    foobar = *argv;
    fo1=fopen(foobar,"wb");

    argc--; argv++;
    foobar = *argv;   
    fo2=fopen(foobar,"wb");
```

The program crashes on the third "argv++". I assumed argv is supposed to get the address of the file I want read in for fp1, then it is a location in memory to create the other two files (fo1, fo2) however after the first increment of argv it becomes null and nothing happens.

Comment: How many arguments are you passing in on the command line?

Comment: None, it just compiles and runs.

Comment: can you please look at your code before posting it, and make sure it's  well indented and everliving is in there?

Comment: this program uses command line arguments. no arguments - fatal errors.

Comment: You need to update this to at least C99.

Comment: `argc` and `argv` are command line parameters. `argc` represents how many parameters are passed and `argv` is a pointer that you can iterate through using `argv++`. If you have no command line arguments this should fail after the first `argv` because `argv` initially points at the program name, I believe.

Comment: That sounds correct @bblincoe , because when I print argv initially it prints where the program is on my system

Comment: Never declare a function like `FILE *fopen();` — always include the header (and you must have done that).  You've removed the protection that the header gives you by removing the prototype for `fopen()`; really, that is just a declaration and not a prototype because it gives no types for the arguments and doesn't even say how many arguments are expected. There's no obvious reason to set and use `foobar`, at least for the first two calls to `fopen()`.  If `foobar` is used later.

Comment: @Ken Try to add some parameters at the command line `program.exe one two three`. Obviously replace `one`, `two`, and `three` with paths to files on your system.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code, the signature of `main`, the unnecessary decrements of `argc`, the unsafe defererencing of `argv` after incrementing it and not checking if the `fopen` calls return a null pointer. Also, you didn't even pass any arguments.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, foobar is used later, and I forgot to add the header.

Comment: "None, it just compiles and runs." -- So you expect it to read your mind for the file names?

Comment: @JimBalter , haha no. I've never read in files like this before and was unsure how it worked. I understand it now

Comment: Reading the documentation for main and argv would have helped. Also examining the values of argc and argv. You say you've been trying to get it to work ... what did that effort consist of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` is a pointer to an array holding the command line arguments. `argv[0]` is a pointer to a string containing the program's filename; `argv[1]` points to a string holding the first command line argument; etc.

`argc` tells you how many arguments there are (including the program's name). So proper code should check this before assuming how many arguments are passed in. If you index `argv` one element beyond the last argument, you'll get a `NULL`. Indexing it beyond that is undefined behavior (you're reading beyond the end of the array).

Comment: @nos good point; edited accordingly to incorporate that. Thanks.